# List files in a specific folder using Flask-FlatPages

Tags: python, flask, flask-flatpages

I use Flask-FlatPages and want to list the files in a specific folder. Until now I only used one level of folders and the following route worked fine:

```
@app.route('/<path:name>')
def articles(name):
    articles = (p for p in pages if p.path.startswith(str(name)))
    folders = listdirs(name)
    return render_template('articles.html', articles=articles, folders=folders)
```

Now I have a folder structure like this:

```
level1/
  level2/
    file1.md
    level3/
      file2.md
```

I get "file1.md" and "file2.md" listed when I'm at the url "/level2". But I just want to list the files in the current directory. How can I change my route to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about flatpages but you can just ignore files with second path separator(/)

so modify your generator if condition to ignore those path